# Traffic Redirect Windows

Tags: networking, redirection, port-redirection

Need help to solve a little problem that i have.
I have a little server where i have multiple ports listening, 81, 82, etc.
Last week in my company all http traffic that doesn't go to the 80/443 port, gets blocked.

I need to access some of my server stuff, so what i want is:

Option A - Redirect all requests that are outside the common ports to the wireless interface

Option B - All requests to a specific domain redirected to the wireless interface

I just want the windows use the wireless interface only for these requests, every other one should go to the wired interface.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure: 1) Your PC is inside of your company network and your server is outside of it, 2) Outgoing HTTP requests to ports other than 80 or 443 are blocked and 3) Your wireless interface can circumvent this blockage? This is not clearly stated in your question. Have you thought about using one standard port (80 and/or 443) on your server and redirecting traffic in your own server (by reverse proxying)?

Comment: 1 - Yes
2 - Yes
3 - Yes (Mobile 4G HotSpot)
It's an option, but the most "complicated" too much to change... :)
After posting this, I was thinking and what I need it's only to add a new route that points to my server IP address and use the IP of the hotpost as the gateway, and should work fine...